# Raspberry Pi Raspbian - check LTE USB modem SIM card phone number

Tags: usb, modem

I have LTE USB modem attached to Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian installed. LTE modem was configured automatically and Internet connection is up.
I don't remember SIM card phone number. How can I check it remotely? I can't disable LTE connection because I use it to communicate with RPi (SSH).

Comment: Ah, you need to call the carrier who sold you the SIM card: https://www.wikihow.com/Get-Your-Mobile-Number-from-Your-SIM.

Comment: This question is off topic, but as an ex mobile planner GSM/3G devices **DO NOT** necessarily know (or even need) an MSISDN; all signalling is based on IMSI - the relationship between MSISDN and IMSI is a network function. Phones which list the MSISDN only do as as a convenience